# Which layout should I use in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I make an app for boosting listening skills. I want to place several EditText like this:
[image]

When I enter some word I want that other words which placed on the right side will be lined break like this:
[image]

Eventually, If the EditBox reaches a screen border I want that he will be lined break with multiline edit property like this:

[image]

My question is which layout should I use and how to do it better. I need any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Flow Layout would work for your basic case, but not sure how it would behave in the multi-line entry case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with flexbox layout: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout. It's a official google library.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.